# professional cv spacing issues

Tags: tables, spacing, cv, sharelatex

I've been trying to figure out how to format this section of [Professional CV from ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv) to make the vertical spacing more tight.

The vertical bar between columns tends to leave more space than necessary after the last entry in the footnotes section. I'm trying to make the bullet list flush left with the description of the project above it.

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, scale=0.8,top=2cm]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section


%final bullet list for projects
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=1em}
\newenvironment{myitemize}
{ \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     }
{ \end{itemize}                  }

% for linkedin/icons
\usepackage{fontawesome}

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

and Projects section

```
%Section: Projects section
\section{Projects}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \emph{KenKen puzzle} &  \textbf{Java} \\\textsc{2014} & Arithmetic and logic puzzle similar to Sudoku\\
 &\footnotesize{\begin{myitemize}
\item Takes a pre-loaded puzzle and determines proper ordering of numbers.
\item Validates the arithmetic restrictions and recursively verifies the solution.
\end{myitemize}} \\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 \emph{Huffman Tree} & \textbf{Java} \\ \textsc{2014} & A Binary Tree used to store character frequency and used to calculate compression ratio.\\ & \footnotesize{\begin{myitemize}
\item Determines which branch to store character based on level of frequency.
\item Utilizes HashMaps, PriorityQueues, and recursion to place the characters within the right node.
\end{myitemize}}\\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\emph{Bird Maze} & \textbf{Java} \\ \textsc{2014} & A maze that consists of bird-like objects that can only go in the direction of their beak. \\ &\footnotesize{\begin{myitemize}
\item Includes the ability to check the path for correctness and discovers the right path.
\item Implements recursive solutions and iterative solutions.
\end{myitemize}} \\ \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\emph{Gettysburg Address} & \textbf{C} \\ \textsc{2014} & A Binary Tree implementation of the Gettysburg Address. \\ &  \footnotesize{\begin{myitemize}
\item Successfully prints out the Gettysburg address via Binary Tree implementation.
\item Correctly used Malloc and Free to obtain and release memory.
\end{myitemize}} \\ 


\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), but `article` instead. Is this correct?

Comment: @Werner you're right. I changed the title, I thought I was using moderncv but in fact I'm using professionalcv from sharelatex's site.

Comment: This template: [Professional-CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cvv)?

Comment: @Werner Yes, that is the one.

Comment: @Werner I've tried implementing a topset=0pt within the itemize setlist section, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a full `tabular`-like implementation - using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) - to set that part of the CV construction. Also, to avoid using a list and set the content as rows inside your table... it's not that difficult to maintain this way, and provides you with the control you want inside such a rigid structure.

[image]

```
% https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%final bullet list for projects
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\blankline}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\}
\newcommand{\projectitem}{\footnotesize\textbullet~\ignorespaces}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
%\font\wm=''Baskerville:color=787878'' at 8pt
%\font\wmweb=''Baskerville:color=FF1493'' at 8pt
%{\wm 
%   \begin{textblock}{1}(0,0)
%       \rotatebox{-90}{\parbox{500mm}{
%           Typeset by Alessandro Plasmati with \XeTeX\  \today\ for 
%           {\wmweb \href{http://www.aleplasmati.comuv.com}{aleplasmati.comuv.com}}
%       }
%   }
%   \end{textblock}
%}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\Huge Alessandro \textsc{Plasmati}
    }\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Someplace, Italy  | dd Month 1912 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & CV Inn 19, 20301, Milano, Italy \\
    \textsc{Phone:}     & +39 123 456789\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}{alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}

%Section: Projects section
\section{Projects}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
 \emph{KenKen puzzle} & \textbf{Java} \\
 \textsc{2014} & Arithmetic and logic puzzle similar to Sudoku \\
 & \projectitem Takes a pre-loaded puzzle and determines proper ordering of numbers. \\
 & \projectitem Validates the arithmetic restrictions and recursively verifies the solution. \\
 \blankline
 \emph{Huffman Tree} & \textbf{Java} \\
 \textsc{2014} & A Binary Tree used to store character frequency and used to calculate compression ratio. \\
 & \projectitem Determines which branch to store character based on level of frequency. \\
 & \projectitem Utilizes HashMaps, PriorityQueues, and recursion to place the characters within the right node. \\
 \blankline
 \emph{Bird Maze} & \textbf{Java} \\
 \textsc{2014} & A maze that consists of bird-like objects that can only go in the direction of their beak. \\
 & \projectitem Includes the ability to check the path for correctness and discovers the right path. \\
 & \projectitem Implements recursive solutions and iterative solutions. \\
 \blankline
 \emph{Gettysburg Address} & \textbf{C} \\
 \textsc{2014} & A Binary Tree implementation of the Gettysburg Address. \\
 & \projectitem Successfully prints out the Gettysburg address via Binary Tree implementation. \\
 & \projectitem Correctly used Malloc and Free to obtain and release memory.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- The use of `\noindent` ensures that the `tabularx` won't be *wider* than `\textwidth` due to a paragraph indent.
- `@{}` removes the tabular column separation on either side of the `tabularx`. This ensures that your widest entries will be flush left (in the first column) and flush right (in the second/last column).
- `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` formats the `X`-column to be `\raggedright` (`\arraybackslash` is required when doing such formatting) which might not be needed, depending on whether you want a justified look or not. I opted for "not".
- `\blankline` inserts a blank line between entries.
- `\projectitem` formats the `itemize`-like structure by setting the text in `\footnotesize` with a `\textbullet`. For a more "`itemize`d look", you could consider using the following definition:

  ```
  \newcommand{\projectitem}{%
    \footnotesize\makebox[1em][l]{\textbullet}%
    \hangindent=1em\ignorespaces}
  ```

Comment: facing the error {Fontin.otf} font not found and I am using the LuaLaTeX

Comment: @MickyK: The fonts form part of the [Professional CV template on ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb8c0933621a613683ecac/v/4/zip?name=Professional%20CV). Download it and place the fonts in your working folder, just like in the template.

Comment: I download the font file from the following http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html and put it in font folder but still found the error.

Comment: @MickyK: Your link provides `Fontin-Regular.otf` while the linked template uses `Fontin.otf`. You may have to rename `Fontin-Regular.otf` to `Fontin.otf` or update the code to use `Fontin-Regular.otf` instead of `Fontin.otf`.

Comment: is there a way to make the text all align with the bullet? The reason I started doing this in the beginning was because I wanted the text to be aligned like a list format. the words "right node" near the huffman tree slightly goes over and I can't seem to get it to not do that. **if that's not possible I totally understand, I'm knew to this and I'm trying to learn more about formatting text.

Comment: @Joshhw: See the updated definition of `\projectitem` at the end of my answer. Use that instead.